# SWC-126 Insuffixient Gas Griefing attack: why not simply requiring a successfull sub-call?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, security

I'm trying to learn more about the SWC Smart Contract Weakness Classification and Test Cases. I'm stuck on understanding SWC-126: https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-126. Especially, I don't understand the proposed solution in the link and how it fixes the attack vector?

Wouldn't this attack vector simply be a sub-case of https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-104? We could simply require the call to be successfull after line 26 of the relayer.sol contract by writing:

`require(success)`

So that the complete transaction reverts in the case that the remaining gas isn't sufficient to execute the sub-call?

Also, I don't understand how the proposed solution in relayer_fixed.sol would fix our problem, since it would only revert the sub-call and the relayer contract would continue without evaluating the pre-vented sub-call?